# Finding all the X and Y coordinates of an image in python opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am a beginner in opencv-python. I want to get all the X and Y coordinates of for the region of the interest mentioned in the code and store it in an array. Can anyone give me an idea on how to proceed? I was able to run the code, but is not showing any results.

Image for detecting all the X and Y coordinates

[image]

The sample code i wrote is written below,

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import imutils
img = cv2.imread("/home/harikrishnan/Desktop/image.jpg",0)
img1 = imutils.resize(img)
img2 = img1[197:373,181:300]  #roi of the image
ans = []
for y in range(0, img2.shape[0]):  #looping through each rows
     for x in range(0, img2.shape[1]): #looping through each column
            if img2[y, x] != 0:
                  ans = ans + [[x, y]]
ans = np.array(ans)
print ans
```

Comment: I'm confused. What does "all the X and Y coordinates of pixels" mean? Isn't that just from 0 to the width of the image × from 0 to the height of the image? What are you trying to accomplish here? This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: X, Y coordinates of what ???

Comment: @YvesDaoust of all pixels of the image or entire image.

Comment: They are (0,0,(1,0)... (W-1,0), (0, 1), (1,1), (W-1,1)... (0,H-1), (1,H-1),... (W-1,H-1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code you are using a `for` loop which is time consuming. You could rather make use of the fast and agile `numpy` library.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import imutils
img = cv2.imread("/home/harikrishnan/Desktop/image.jpg",0)
img1 = imutils.resize(img)
img2 = img1[197:373,181:300]  #roi of the image

indices = np.where(img2!= [0])
coordinates = zip(indices[0], indices[1])
```

- I used the numpy.where() method to retrieve a tuple indices of two arrays where the first array contains the x-coordinates of the white points and the second array contains the y-coordinates of the white pixels.

`indices` returns:

```
(array([  1,   1,   2, ..., 637, 638, 638], dtype=int64),
 array([292, 298, 292, ...,  52,  49,  52], dtype=int64))
```

- I then used the `zip()` method to get a list of tuples containing those points.

Printing `coordinates` gives me a list of coordinates with edges:

```
[(1, 292), (1, 298), (2, 292), .....(8, 289), (8, 295), (9, 289), (9, 295), (10, 288)]
```