# how to put the image from folder into cycle

Tags: python, python-3.x, image

I have this code. But i need to find xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax for all images from folder and after this put name of the image, parametres in list dict. I do not understand how to put this from folder to string (#read image)(i mean, ***img = cv2.imread('C:\Blobs\SR1.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)*** - it is O.K.
but when ***img = cv2.imread('SR1.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)*** - error). And if it is possible, how to do this by cycle.

```
import os
FOLDER_PATH = r'C:\\Blobs'

def listDir(dir):
  fileNames = os.listdir(dir)
  for fileName in fileNames:
    print('File Name: ' + fileName)
    print('Folder Path: ' + os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dir,fileName)), 
sep='\n')
if __name__ == '__main__':
  listDir(FOLDER_PATH)##
import cv2

# read image
img = cv2.imread('C:\\Blobs\\SR1.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

xmin = 0
ymin = 0
ymax = img.shape[0] - 1
xmax = img.shape[1] - 1

print('xmin       : ', xmin)
print('xmax       : ', xmax)
print('ymin       : ', ymin)
print('ymax       : ', ymax)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding all the X and Y coordinates of an image in python opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44068654/finding-all-the-x-and-y-coordinates-of-an-image-in-python-opencv)

Comment: @APhillips i think no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that `xmin` and `ymin` will always be `0` and `xmax` and `ymax` will be equal to the dimensions of the image - `1`. You can use `opencv` package for it, you need to `pip` install it. Once you have it you can just do this:

```py
import os
import cv2

def get_dimensions(img_path):
    # read image
    img = cv2.imread(img_path, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

    xmin = 0
    ymin = 0 
    ymax = 
    xmax = img.shape[1] - 1

    return {
        'xmin': 0,
        'xmax': img.shape[0] - 1,
        'ymin': 0,
        'ymax': img.shape[0] - 1
    }

def list_files(dir_path):
    files_and_folders = [
      os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dir_path,file_or_folder)) for file_or_folder in os.listdir(dir_path)
    ]
    return [file for file in files_and_folders if os.path.isfile(file)]


def get_img_data(dir_path):
    return [
        {**get_dimensions(img_path), 'name':os.path.basename(img_path)} for img_path in list_files(dir_path)
    ]
```

This is an example, I use the function `get_img_data` with the path `/tmp/`, it will look for all files in that directory and read them (be sure the directory path you use contains only images), then in `output` I store the result, which I print, it will have the `xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax` values and the `name` of the file.

```
output = get_img_data('/tmp/')
print(output)
>>> '[{'xmin': 0, 'xmax': 199, 'ymin': 0, 'ymax': 199, 'name': 'a.png'}, {'xmin': 0, 'xmax': 199, 'ymin': 0, 'ymax': 199, 'name': 'b.png'}]'
```

Comment: @АнтонТугусов edited the answer, next time mark it as the accepted answer and then make another question.

Comment: I do not quite understand where to indicate the path to the directory

Comment: @АнтонТугусов you just use get_img_data(path_of_dir)